# Unrecognized matlab path while working with fieldtrip

Tags: matlab

Installed FieldTrip Toolbox in Matlab, but it keeps on giving this path error all the time.

```
Error in ft_defaults (line 187)
  ft_warning('FieldTrip is not yet on your MATLAB path, adding %s', strrep(ftPath, '\\', '\'));
Warning: Your path is set up incorrectly. You probably used addpath(genpath('path_to_fieldtrip')), this can lead to
unexpected behavior.
```

Also tried adding a path with the command

```
addpath('C:\Users\hp\Desktop\MATLAB Add-Ons\Collections\FieldTrip(2)')
```

Pleases Help.

Comment: Do you have another version of FieldTrip somewhere on the computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had problems installing fieldtrip for the first time. Make sure you dont add the subfolders to the path, and only the fieldtrip directory.

The following code made it work for me:

```
restoredefaultpath;
clear RESTOREDEFAULTPATH_EXECUTED;
addpath('C:\Users\hp\Desktop\MATLAB Add-Ons\Collections\FieldTrip(2)');
ft_defaults;
```

Hope it helps!